# How to customize B2C Expired Password Message

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using B2C Custom Flows. If a user tries to signon with an expired password (older than 90 days) a message "The password has expired" is displayed. How can I customize this message. I could not find this message in the list of localized string ids https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids.

Comment: Hi @Douglas Woods. Is this occurring because `passwordPolicies` is *not* set to `DisablePasswordExpiration`?

Comment: I have NOT set the DisablePasswordExpiration in  passwordPolicies, as I do want the password to expire after 90 days. But I would like to customize the message that is displayed when the pass word has expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **user** object must be created with the **passwordPolicies** property set to `DisablePasswordExpiration`.

This is because [the **local-NonInteractive** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/d20bb35939124503f10661963c5e3129603eea95/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L409) fails if the password for the user has expired.

Since you are creating custom flows, then you can implement your own password policy with your own localized messages, such as that in [this **Azure AD B2C: Force password reset after 90 days** sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no password expiration policy for local accounts.Did you create a local account DisablePasswordExpiration without setting the passwordPolicies attribute to?

1.If the local account is created through the built-in password policy, this policy will set the passwordPolicies attribute to DisablePasswordExpiration.

2.If you create a local account through a custom policy or Azure AD Graph API, you must manually set the passwordPolicies attribute to DisablePasswordExpiration.